# How to count result from two columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a prediction table including homescore and awayscore. I want to output all distinct predictions and how many instances of each prediction exists.

```
matchid    homescore    awayscore
 1         1            2
 1         1            0
 1         9            3
 1         2            0
 1         1            2
 1         1            0
 2         3            2
 2         2            2
...
```

I want this to output a table like this for matchid 1:

```
result    predictions
1-2       2           
1-0       2
9-3       1
2-0       1
```

Comment: `SELECT homescore,awayscore,COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY homescore,awayscore;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(homescore, '-', awayscore) as result,
    COUNT(*) as predictions
FROM table
WHERE matched = 1
GROUP BY CONCAT(homescore, '-', awayscore);
```

Comment: mark your query is missing one thing.. i was going to post an answer but you beat me to it lol.. instead of posting the same answer.. just add a `WHERE matchid = 1` per the OP request

Comment: @JohnRuddell - duly added

Comment: I just edited your query :) youre where was below the group by

Comment: And then you would output the result in an while loop?

Comment: You were asking about the database query, how you execute that query and how you output the results depends on which interface you're using (MySQL, MySQLi, PDO) and whether you're using a framework or MVC separation, etc.... but there's plenty of examples in the PHP docs

Comment: I'm sorry if I was a bit unclear; my intention was to output the table (the second one) from the post. That will include both database query and the following script to output correct data. For me, it sounds reasonable to use a while loop through MySQLi!?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to use a loop through the resultset: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php though I'd use a `while` loop: `while($row = $result->fetch_object()){...}`

Comment: Thank you. The only concern I got now, is that the query is ordering by the result, while I want it to order by number of predictions (the result with the most predictions on top). Can I use "Order by" for this?

Comment: Yes, you can order by the number of predictions

Comment: Thank you. The final database query looks like this: SELECT CONCAT(homescore, '-', awayscore) as result, COUNT(1) as predictions FROM fxweb_predictiondata WHERE matchid = ".$matchid." GROUP BY CONCAT(homescore, '-', awayscore) ORDER BY predictions DESC